# How to format curl command with username and password in cloudformation using Join and Ref

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

What I'm trying:

```
UserData:
  'Fn::Base64': !Sub|
   #!/bin/bash -xe

   curl -k -f -u !Join [":",[ !Ref User, !Ref, Pass] ] -O https://myartifacctory/.../myfile
```

/var/log/messages is saying enter password for user !Join

User and Pass are parameters that are passed into cloudformation as parameters.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
UserData:
  'Fn::Base64': !Sub |
   #!/bin/bash -xe

   curl -k -f -u ${User}:${Pass} -O https://myartifacctory/.../myfile
```

The `${MyVarName}` syntax is explained in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html):

> A string with variables that AWS CloudFormation substitutes with their associated values at runtime. **Write variables as ${MyVarName}**.